# Api Context props Boolean don't turn

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**What I try to do**

I try to use apiContext with ThemeProvider, when the user want switch a light mode to dark mode, my state doesn't want change.

**My operative mode**

I create an interface themeContext files for manage types and initialize context.

A themeContext file for call createContext and made a custom hook.

A ThemeProvider for pass my constant 'theme' is always a boolean and an a method for switch it.

In my template I have a part of logic for call the hook and mutate turn the theme.

My console return always false, what's going wrong. I deliberately omitted react's imports.

**My code**

IthemeContext.ts

```js
export interface IThemeContext {
    theme: boolean;
    toggleTurn?: () => void;
}

export const defaultThemeState: IThemeContext = {
    theme: false,
    toggleTurn: () => !defaultThemeState.theme
}
```

themeContext.ts

```js
import {defaultThemeState, IThemeContext} from "../interface/IThemeContext";

const ThemeContext = React?.createContext<Partial<IThemeContext>>(defaultThemeState);

export const useThemeContext = () => useContext(ThemeContext);

export default ThemeContext;
```

ThemeProvider

```js
(…)
import ThemeContext, {useThemeContext} from "../context/themeContext";

export const ThemeProvider: FC<{children: ReactNode}> = ({ children}) => {
    const {theme, toggleTurn} = useThemeContext();

    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={
            {
                theme,
                toggleTurn
            }
        }>
            { children }
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ThemeProvider;
```

App.tsx

```js
(…)
import Template from "./component/template";
import {ThemeProvider} from "./component/provider/theme.provider";

function App() {

    return (
        <ThemeProvider>
            <Template />
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}

export default App
```

Template.tsx

```js
(…)
const Template: FC = (): ReactElement<any, any> | null => {

    const { theme, toggleTurn } = useThemeContext();

    const toggleTheme = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (toggleTurn) {
            toggleTurn();
            console.log(theme);
        }
    };

    return (
    (…)
       <button type="button" onClick={ 
            (e: React.MouseEvent<HMTLButtonElement) => 
               toggleTheme(e)
       }
    (…)
    )
```

Comment: You should declare and pass a state variable/setter function (`const [theme, toggleTurn] = useState(false);`) to your context provider instead.

Comment: I appreciate @juliomalves your intervention, but my objectives is used ContextApi and I must made my hook with createContext and useContext.

Comment: `useThemeContext` hook is meant to be used by the _consumers_ of the context, not in the context _provider_ itself. To keep track of the variables in the context provider you should use a state variable (line I suggested above).